# Trying to create new Hive datasoure in pentaho 5.0.1, getting following error

Tags: hadoop, hive, pentaho

I am using Hadoop-2.7.1

Error connecting to database [Hive] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
    Error occured while trying to connect to the database

```
Error connecting to database: (using class org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver)
Unable to load Hive Server 2 JDBC driver for the currently active Hadoop configuration


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver)
Unable to load Hive Server 2 JDBC driver for the currently active Hadoop configuration


at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:415)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:353)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:306)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:294)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:84)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2459)
at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:541)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:329)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swing.tags.SwingButton$OnClickRunnable.run(SwingButton.java:58)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:154)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1082)
at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1655)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1607)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swing.tags.SwingDialog.show(SwingDialog.java:238)
at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:254)
at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.ConnectionPanel$AddDataSourceAction.actionPerformed(ConnectionPanel.java:252)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3312)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:154)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1082)
at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1655)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1607)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.CommonDialog.setVisible(CommonDialog.java:281)
at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.CommonDialog.performEdit(CommonDialog.java:193)
at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.JdbcDataSourceDialog.performConfiguration(JdbcDataSourceDialog.java:788)
at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.JdbcDataSourcePlugin.performEdit(JdbcDataSourcePlugin.java:71)
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.wizard.ui.xul.steps.DataSourceAndQueryStep.editOrCreateDataFactory(DataSourceAndQueryStep.java:426)
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.wizard.ui.xul.steps.DataSourceAndQueryStep.createDataFactory(DataSourceAndQueryStep.java:405)
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.wizard.ui.xul.steps.DataSourceAndQueryStep$DatasourceAndQueryStepHandler.doCreateDataFactory(DataSourceAndQueryStep.java:165)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:329)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swing.tags.SwingButton$OnClickRunnable.run(SwingButton.java:58)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:154)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1082)
at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1655)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1607)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swing.tags.SwingDialog.show(SwingDialog.java:238)
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.wizard.ui.xul.EmbeddedWizard.run(EmbeddedWizard.java:152)
at org.pentaho.reporting.designer.extensions.wizard.NewWizardReportAction.actionPerformed(NewWizardReportAction.java:81)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3312)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error connecting to database: (using class org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver)
Unable to load Hive Server 2 JDBC driver for the currently active Hadoop configuration

at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:540)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:399)
... 151 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load Hive Server 2 JDBC driver for the currently active Hadoop configuration
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.getActiveDriver(HiveDriver.java:107)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.callWithActiveDriver(HiveDriver.java:121)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:132)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:233)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:528)
... 152 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.getActiveDriver(HiveDriver.java:105)
... 157 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load JDBC driver of type: hive2
at org.pentaho.hadoop.shim.common.CommonHadoopShim.getJdbcDriver(CommonHadoopShim.java:109)
... 162 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: JDBC driver of type 'hive2' not supported
at org.pentaho.hadoop.shim.common.CommonHadoopShim.getJdbcDriver(CommonHadoopShim.java:104)
... 162 more
```

Hostname       : localhost
Port           : 10000
Database name  : default

Comment: I found the answer in [this](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?151796-Database-connection-error-for-Impala-using-Pentaho-5-trail-version) link. By edit property "active.hadoop.configuration" in "plugin.properties"